# How to install flyway from a GitHub feature branch?

Tags: database, github, flyway, clickhouse

I want to use flyway as a database migration tool for our BDs in clickhouse, unfortunately flyway by default does not support clickhouse migration, but I found [this PR](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/3333) in flyway GitHub repository that fixes my problem, but I don't know how should I install flyway of [this](https://github.com/f1yegor/flyway/tree/clickhouse-support) feature branch on the PR.

I have tried installing flyway with brew on my local MacOS but it always installs the latest version of flyway (the one that does not support clickhouse).

Comment: We (Redgate) are going to be adding Clickhouse into the Flyway repository in the next few weeks so which will resolve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better use https://github.com/bytebase/bytebase/?

Try following commands

```
git clone git@github.com:f1yegor/flyway.git
cd flyway
git checkout clickhouse-support
mvn clean
mvn package
find ./ -name *.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked `Bytebase`, but it does not fit our needs, we want a simple CLI based tool to run in a CI/CD workflow. `Bytebase` seems an overkill as it has so many features we don't need, it has a paywall for some features and uses and also it should be deployed on cluster to enable use of the UI. We ended up going with [migrate-golang](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) instead as it is easy to integrate with `clickhosue` and has a pretty neat CLI.

Comment: for simple CI/CD schema migration i used https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly what we ended up doing for our setup.